# Replace responsive div background on rollover and click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with realizing how I would code a div's background which requires a dynamic  background.  The div has a specific height but the width is the size of the browser.

I have a div which has a default repeat-all background pattern but changes if a button is hovered over or clicked on.  The backgrounds do NOT repeat so I'm trying to figure out how to have them expand/resize based on the browser size which is the div size.

Here is what it should look like... Default: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogxrh.png Category 1 (Hover/Pressed): https://i.stack.imgur.com/260i8.png

Notice how default is repeating pattern and the other is a full-bg.

My code is currently:

```
$("#select_all").click(function(e) {
        $("#selected-game").removeClass('game_bg_minecraft').removeClass('game_bg_terraria').removeClass('game_bg_dayz');
     });
     $("#select_minecraft").click(function(e) {
        $("#selected-game").addClass('game_bg_minecraft').removeClass('game_bg_terraria').removeClass('game_bg_dayz');
     });
     $("#select_terraria").click(function(e) {
        $("#selected-game").addClass('game_bg_terraria');
     });
     $("#select_dayz").click(function(e) {
        $("#selected-game").addClass('game_bg_dayz');
     });
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="selected-game">
<div class="row">
    <div class="ten columns">
    <h1>TopTitle</h1>
        <div>
        <h4>Selected Game Title</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="game-selection">   
    <div class="select_game">
        <button id="select_all" class="demo-change btn btn-info" style="display: inline-block;">Default</button>
        <button id="select_minecraft" class="demo-change btn btn-info" style="display: inline-block;">Category1</button>
        <button id="select_terraria" class="demo-change btn btn-info" style="display: inline-block;">Category2</button>
        <button id="select_dayz" class="demo-change btn btn-info" style="display: inline-block;">Category3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="game-options">
        More stuff here, yo!
    </div>
</div>
```

But the problem here is that for every new button i add, i need to remove all other classes or risk the new background not showing up.  I'm also lost as to how to have one background repeat while having the other dynamically resize based on div's width.

I'm also not sure how to cleanly and optimally change for both click and hover while keeping js code to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make general background class that repeats but centers:

```
.game-bg{
    background: url("default-bg.jpg) repeat center;
}
```

and just change the background property:

```
$("#select_item1").click(function(e) {
    $("#selected-game").css('background-image', 'url("myimage.jpg")');
});
```

Just make sure you use images that are large enough to display nicely on big monitors. Because the background image centers it expands and crops on the left and right side.

Another way to go would be to look at the background-size property (but this isn't supported in all browsers):

http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Specificly *auto* or *cover*.

Follow up question:

If you use jQuery to remove the CSS again it should convert back to the default .game-bg class background:

```
$("#selected-game").css('background-image', ''); //leave the background empty
```

However if you i.e. click on one of the items.... and then hover over the other items. It will revert to the default background, and not of the "active" item. If you also want that it becomes a bit more complex. Then you should add an active class to the item that is active. And on mouseout look for the item with the active class, lookup the ID and based on the ID apply the right background. I hope this makes any sense :-)

Comment: Thanks! I'm playing around with the background-size property for now.
Any idea on how I could do a mouseover and mouseout with this as well? I was trying adding and removing classes but then problems arise where it resets to the default background if i mousein and then mouseout on the current selected background.


   $("#select_minecraft").mouseover(function(e) {
        $("#selected-game").addClass('game_bg_minecraft');
       });
       $("#select_minecraft").mouseout(function(e) {
        $("#selected-game").removeClass('game_bg_minecraft');
       });

Comment: Your code is hard to read. But if I understand correctly you want to try to use my method of one class, combined with the background-size property, but not with clicks, but mouse hovers. See my edit in a few minutes

Comment: Terribly sorry about messy code. I've put it into jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k2wft/ What I'm wondering is how to also get the backgrounds to change if someone were to hover over a button. Problem I'm having at this time is that a mouseover/mouseout clears which button is select so that on a mouseout with no button press, the abckground goes back to the default if that makes sense.

//edit: just read your edit and realized you answer this via active class.  I'll try playing around with that. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/KNqVx/ I added an data-bg attribute to simply the code, and add and remove an "active" class to identify the correct background to go back to. I think this is what you need :-) Please note, you provided only 3 background instead of 4, so 1 is used twice.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for in a really simple-ish mannor. Thanks for taking the time to simplify and comment the code. Really appreciate your time and help. =)

Comment: The code I wrote can be cleaned up an simplified a bit further but is usable :-) good luck with your site!

Answer (score 1):

try using `background-size:100%`  it's a css3 property that will resize the background image based on it's container

for more information checkout w3schools [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: @MCG looks like Darwayne beat me to it ;-) I also posted this property as a potential solution. However, like I mentioned, have a good look at browser support as it is only IE9 and up. Good luck!